# ¿Como recuperar un campo de una llave foranea, para ser utilizado en otro formulario sin ser modificado el campo a recuperar?

Tags: html, python, django

Tengo la siguiente interfaz gráfica

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En donde quiero dar de baja a un producto, recuperando el código en el nuevo formulario "Dar Baja".

Este es mi código

#### Código `models.py`

```
 class venta(models.Model):
     codigo = models.IntegerField()
     descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
     marca = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=True)
     precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=5, default=0)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return '{}'.format(self.codigo)

 class baja(models.Model):
     Venta = models.ForeignKey(venta)
     fecha_baja = models.DateField()
     observacion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     estado = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

#### Código de `forms.py`

```
class baja_form(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = baja
      fields = ['Venta', 'fecha_baja', 'observacion','estado']
      labels = {}

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(baja_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in iter(self.fields):
        if field <> 'estado':
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
```

#### Código de `urls.py`

```
url(r'^crear_bajas/$', views.crear_baja, name='crear_bajas'),
```

#### Código del documento html donde está el botón de Dar Baja

```
 <a onclick="return abrir_modal('{% url 'venta:crear_bajas' %}','Dar de Baja / Nuevo')" class="btn btn-warning"  type="button">Dar Baja</a>
```

#### Código donde está el Formulario de Bajas

```
 <form role="form" action="{% url 'venta:crear_bajas' %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">
        {{ form.as_p }}
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Guardar">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return cerrar_modal()">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Hasta ahorita el resultado es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En lugar de ese `select` quisiera poder recuperar el "*código*" del producto sin que el usuario lo modifique, es lo único que no puedo hacer aún.

#### Código `views.py` de la vista de la tabla

```
 def ventas_list(request):
     ventas_p = venta.objects.all().order_by('-id')
     contexto = {'ventas':ventas_p}
     return render(request, 'ventas/ventalist.html', contexto)
```

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo es que muestras cada fila de la tabla de ventas?

Comment: voy a agregar esa parte mas al codigo

Answer (score 1):

primero carga los tipos de formularios:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
```

segundo para este caso vas a usar

```
DeleteView
```

despues en tu vista:

```
class baja(DeleteView): 
    model = "tu modelo"
    template_name = "tu template"
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):

    "aca pones lo que queres eliminar"
```

"ESPERO SEA DE AYUDA"